# Datatable cellEditor functionality in forEach generated Datatable

Tags: foreach, primefaces, datatable, jstl

I am trying to generate a editable datatable dynamically dependend on the resultset of an previously executed SQL-Query.
Depending on which columns would have a constant value I am trying to not render them. That part of the code works just fine, everything is displayed as i would like it to be. 
My issues are with the cellEditor. I generate my datable as follows:

```
    <p:dataTable ajax="true" var="mBT" value="#{stammdaten.bbvList}" id="meldeBearbeitungsTable" editable="true" editMode="cell" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400" style="width:600px">
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{stammdaten.onCellEdit}" update=":Mb:message"/>
    <c:forEach var="column" items="#{stammdaten.columns}">
        <p:column headerText="#{column.header}">
            <f:attribute name="myCol" value="#{column}" />
            <span>
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{mBT[column.property]}"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{mBT[column.property]}">
                            <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9]/i"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </span>
        </p:column>
      </c:forEach>
    </p:dataTable>
```

bbvList is a List of beans with different values.

columns is a List of beans to identify the header-Texts coresponding to the respective variables.

So now the issue itself:
This is how the cellEditor looks like when i click on it:
[Issue-Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP16D.png)

So in that example i tried to edit the field with the value "8" in it. onCellEdit gets triggered (a System.out.println is getting printed on the console) but i cant actually change the value in the respective field.

Does have cellEdit issues with the forEach initialisition of the dataTable? If yes is there a way to fix it? Else what am i doing wrong?

Since only a specific component of the html-side of code isnt working as it should be i won't post unnecessary java-Code for now. If needed i will add that as well.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: You generate a `<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{stammdaten.onCellEdit}" update=":Mb:message"/>` for each column. Don't do that, move it outside the loop. Not sure it solves anything, but it is not good

Comment: Fixed that, I think i had it originally outside of the loop, got it inside in my efforts towards a solution of the problem prior to posting the question. However that sadly wasnt the source of issue.

Comment: Tried removeing `<f:attribute name="myCol" value="#{column}" /><span>....</span>` to? In making a [mcve]. Oh and what is you PF version? Tried the latest (just for this issue)?

Comment: Somehow the attribute and/or span were causing the problem. Thanks for bringning me on the right track :)

Comment: Next time **always** create a [mcve]. You'd have found it yourself then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the attribute and/or span where the cause of the problem. Simply removing them solved the issue with the cellEdit.
following works fine :

```
<p:dataTable ajax="true" var="mBT" value="#{stammdaten.bbvList}" id="meldeBearbeitungsTable" editable="true" editMode="cell" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400" style="width:600px">
  <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{stammdaten.onCellEdit}" update=":Mb:message"/>
  <c:forEach var="column" items="#{stammdaten.columns}">
    <p:column headerText="#{column.header}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mBT[column.property]}"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mBT[column.property]}">
                        <p:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9]/i"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
  </c:forEach>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: No, I mean the "the and/or where" sentence in the beginning of you text. Tags are not visible there....